# How do I handle injectables in tests for an Aurelia CLI project using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, aurelia

My project is organized as such:

- App (Creates a router from 'aurelia-router')

  - Wizard (Routed component; injects the router - along with some custom stuff)

    - Steps (Collection of Step objects in Wizard; each Step has a reference to parent Wizard)

      - Questions (Collection of Question objects in Step; each Question has a reference to parent Step and parent Wizard)

I'm trying to test functionality of a Question object, but in order to do so I need a Step and a Wizard so references don't break.

Creating an instance of the Wizard object means I need to provide the injectables to the constructor, which is easy for my custom stuff and nice for providing a mock. But creating the Router from scratch seems wrong and I don't know how or if it's even possible to get Router from App within a test.

So, my question is, is there a way to get access to my instance of Router within App from a test so I can provide it to my Wizard constructor? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Have you tried to look on aurelia router [test](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/master/test/)?

Comment: I have. I will probably end up doing that as it seems it may be the only way to accomplish what I want.

Comment: How about using aurelia.container, you can get all registered modules there.